# regex error with ISBN search

Tags: php, regex

hello can anyone see what is wrong with this regex? i got it from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) and have tested it on [this](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php) and it all checked out, yet i get this error

Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

here is my code

```
$input = $item_details['description'];
$regex = '^[0-9]{9}[[0-9]|X|x]$^';
preg_match($input, $regex, $output);
echo ($output);
```

Comment: The regex on that page is: "^[0-9]{9}[[0-9]|X|x]$".  Note there's no '^' at the end and it's in double quotes not single.  Not sure if that helps, I haven't/won't use php.

Comment: i got it now i mixed up the varaibles its regex first then the string to be searched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]{9}([0-9]|X|x)$/';
```

or

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]{9}[0-9Xx]$/';
```

or

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]{9}[0-9X]$/i';
```

Comment: thanks for the response! it gave me the same error however Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash